# Discrete Math- Four different dice are rolled

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Four different dice are rolled. a) In how many outcomes will at least one five appear? b) In how many outcomes will the highest die be a five?

I think i figured out the answer for how many outcomes will the five appear at least once. So what I got was that there are total of 6^4 of total outcomes which is 1296 - 5^4 = 671 outcomes for at least on five to appear. (correct me if im wrong). Though I have no idea how to approach question b)? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Part (a) looks good. The highest die being a five is the same thing as saying you rolled at least one five and you rolled no sixes.

Comment: if I coun't that I rolled no sixes, that wouldn't make sense because the highest number can be a different number too? highest die can be a 4? or a 3? or a 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** All rolls are $\le 5$ and it is not true that all rolls are $\le 4$.

(We interpreted "the highest is $5$" to mean one *or more* $5$'s occur, but nothing higher.)

Comment: so I would approach it by considering that I rolled no sixes, right?

Comment: The hint leads directly  to the answer $5^4-4^4$. Forget about $6$'s (though you could do it that way too).

Comment: The answer for part b is $5^{4} - 4^{4}$? I am having a bit of trouble understanding why. Does $5^{4}$ mean rolls with only 1-5, excluding 6?